# Firefox - Middle click yields unexpected behaviour

Tags: firefox, linux-mint

When I middle click anywhere on a page other than a link, it'll take me to a page that I've already been at since opening Firefox, and keep doing it every time I middle-click something that isn't a link. I can't find a pattern as to what page it chooses, and it seems to me like it chooses pages at random intervals and stop after a random amount of time, or sometimes not at all.

Can someone please tell me what's going on, and how I can disable this behavior?

I'm running Firefox 21.0 on Linux Mint 14 with MATE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's "pasting" the contents of clipboard as the URL to open.

You can disable it by typing `about:config` into the location bar, searching for `middlemouse.contentLoadURL`, and setting it to `false`.